# Database structure for new user account

Tags: mysql

what should be database structure (fields in a table) for a user account. what I want when an admin create a new user account, the account should be in Inactive state until the user set the password. 
When the admin create the user account it create a url and send to that user on his registered email-Id when he open that url the user see a page for setting password. when he set the password the user account should be activated.
my sample Database structure is below

```
CREATE TABLE user_account (
user_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
fst_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
lst_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
email_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
login_password VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
user_created_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `email_id` (`email_id`)
)
```

I want to know should I add more field's in the table or a new table for accomplishing this task.

Comment: If you consider the account active when a password is set and inactive if not, all your described requirements should be met by your structure. If there are any more specific requirements (e.G. time of activation...) please specify them in your question.

Comment: And what would you tell him if he needed the 'time of activation'?

Comment: what I want is when the user account is activated then only the user should be able to login otherwise not.

Comment: means the admin have only authority to create the user account, not for set the password.

Answer (score 0):

The database structure is a result of what **you** require your user-related processes should be like. You can derive from the requirements you enumerated what fields you would need. This is, however, not a technical but a model-related question. The answers to this are more or less straight-forward.

1. If you need the time of registration, create a `date` field
2. If you need the user's IP on registration, create a `varchar` field
3. If you need to know which user has created this account (e.g. an Admin), create a field that references another `User`
4. If you need the user to have different states (DEACTIVATED, DELETED etc.), create a `varchar` or and `int` field and define in your application what values it may have.